# Microsoft Azure AD Applications

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, group-policy, microsoft-graph-api

I've registered an application (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) in Microsoft Azure AD to be able to work with MS Graph API for creating the groups and teams programmatically. Now I'm able to call the MS Graph API and create the groups. The issue I'm having right now is I have a naming policy like this `<Department> - <Group name>` in Azure AD and as I call the MS Graph API with the application identity and as I don't have any department for my app, the department part is always empty. I would like to know if there is a way to set department or other attributes for the app in Azure AD?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to add attribute for the app in azure ad.